# Winforms UserControl does not resize itself considering its Container(DockPanel)

Tags: c#, winforms, layout

In Windows Forms, C#, I created a `UserControl` and placed some controls into it, like `Tab Control` and some `Grid Control`s. They fulfill the `UserControl` from border to border, but when I load the `UserControl` into a `DockPanel` dynamically, the `UserControl` itself does not stretch to the borders of the `DockPanel`.

Comment: try show the code, that loads the code into the dockpanel

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`UserControl` has no anchor or dock editor on the design screen properties, and I did something like this:

```
private void MyUserControl1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
}
```